# Why do I have only private keys for some SSH connections but I have to generate key pairs for other SSH connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-codecommit

When I create an EC2 Ubuntu instance on AWS, it generates a key pair. Then it has me download the private key from that key pair. I use that private key with `ssh -i` to connect to the EC2 instance.

To use AWS CodeCommit, AWS asks me to create a key pair on my machine using `ssh-keygen`. Why do I want two keys? Why doesn't AWS generate the key pair? Can this key pair be used with connecting to other (non-AWS) entities? Can I use a key pair that I generated for connections to a non-AWS entity to connect to AWS CodeCommit?

Why is there a difference between these two SSH-setup approaches and are these approaches interchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate one ssh key or use even pre-existing ssh key and then you can generate many public key from one ssh private key. What AWS needs in both cases a public key to authenticate you.

The option `-y` outputs the public key. From the linux/mac manual for the `ssh-keygen` command:

> `-y` ---- This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print
> an
> OpenSSH public key to stdout.

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

[SSH and Linux, macOS, or Unix: Set up the public and private keys for Git and CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html#setting-up-ssh-unixes-keys)

> Instead of using Amazon EC2 to create your key pair, you can create an RSA key pair using a third-party tool and then import the public key to Amazon EC2.

[Import your own public key to Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws)